# How do I zoom out in Unity's play mode?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity, following [this rolling ball tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/roll-ball-tutorial/moving-camera?playlist=17141) and I think I clicked something but my play mode camera is super zoomed in. How do I fix it?

I can't seem to upload it but here are pics.

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1TLx.jpg
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/eohNr.jpg

Comment: its a bug, sometimes that happens. use the slider just above the play mode screen, setit to something bigger than 1, than reset it to 1

Comment: The scale slider? I tried that, just zooms in more

Comment: You most likely move your camera in a script somewhere.

Comment: It's the same script as the one in the tutorial, exact same.

Comment: JK, you were right, I had a = instead of -. whoops, thanks